# How get only first part XPath - WooCommerce

Tags: xml, xpath, woocommerce

i have problem with XPath. I'm trying to download products from an xml file but i need only products with "Category One". My path in xml:

`<category id="1214553883" name="Category One/Category Two"/>`

How can I get all the categories that are in the name Category One?

I am using the All Import plugin for wordpress.

Comment: Share code you've tried and clarify whether you want element that *contains* `"Category One"` `name` attribute or *exactly equal* to `"Category One"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following xpath in your condition :

Xpath=`.//*[contains(@name,'Category One')]`

Note that it will return all elements with matching name with Category One.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: It will of course also return an element with `name="Category Zero/Category One"`. We have no way of knowing from your question whether that's the result you want.